# Google Drive custom properties - Date data type?

Tags: google-drive-api

Does Google Drive support date data type for custom properties?
At present, Google Drive custom properties seems to support only text.

Answer (score 2):

[Custom File Properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/properties) are stored as a string, but I don't see why you couldn't put a date into the string.

The following is an integer CatagorieId, stored as a string.

```
{
  'key':        'CatagorieID',
  'value':      '92348',
  'visibility': 'PRIVATE'
}
```

Answer: Custom properties are stored as strings.
Recommendation:  Store your date as a string?

Comment: If date is stored as string, we cannot support range searches - example, find documents that have a specific custom date property which has values within last month.

Comment: @cdeep that's correct. It's just string key-value pairs.